# Setting CNAME at abc.example.com to redirect to amazon EC2 instance

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, redirect, cname-record, rewrite

This is linked to this question:

[Redirecting to the IP of an amazon EC2 instance](https://serverfault.com/questions/23650/redirecting-to-the-ip-of-an-amazon-ec2-instance)

I am able to create a "subdomain", but NOT the CNAME record because 1&1 (my domain name registrar) says:

The domain name you entered is too long.

I'm trying to get it to redirect to (anonymized):
ec2-904-996-299-992.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't make comments, but is ec2-904-996-299-992.compute-1.amazonaws.com linked to a static or dynamic ip ?

If it is static instead of creating a CNAME you can create a A record pointing to the IP which would be the same thing.

Comment: It's actually a 'dynamic' instance at this time, but eventually we'll be using a reserved instance. I ended up using the IP address mechanism (via Elastic IP), but which one is better? CNAME or A?

Comment: they are pretty much the same, the only difference is that linking it to the CNAME will eventually lead it to the IP which is the A record, you could say it is merelly a way of naming numbers to a more conventional term

Comment: ah! of course... that makes sense!

Comment: Went the 'A' route! :)

Comment: :) glad you managed it out.